# How to stop a stroke repeat animation in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

How to control the `Rectangle` animation repeat or not by assigning binding property `isRepeatAnimation`?

What I expect is that after assigning `true` to `isRepeatAnimation`, the border width animate from 5.0 to 0.0 and back and forth, and the repeat animation is off after assigning `false` to `isRepeatAnimation`.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var isRepeatAnimation: Bool
    @State var lineWidth: CGFloat = 5
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .stroke(Color.blue, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: lineWidth))
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .animation(isRepeatAnimation ? repeatAnimation : Animation.easeInOut, value: lineWidth)
    }
    
    var repeatAnimation: Animation {
        Animation.easeInOut.repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
    }
}

struct ContentViewPreviewer: View {
    @State var repeated = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ContentView(isRepeatAnimation: $repeated)
            Button("Toggle") { 
                repeated.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentViewPreviewer()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop repeating animation it we should replace it with default one, and line width can be just toggled.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.4

[image: demo]

Here is main fixes:

```
Rectangle()
    .stroke(Color.blue, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: isRepeatAnimation ? 0 : lineWidth))
    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    .animation(isRepeatAnimation ? repeatAnimation : Animation.default, value: isRepeatAnimation)
```

[Complete test module in project](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestToggledReppeatingAnimation.swift)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But if the default value of `repeated` is `true`, it does not display before hitting toggle. I would be more grateful if this problem could be solved

Comment: If you want to run animation on launch just toggle `repeated` in `.onAppear`. To make animation run there must be some change. And btw - it's out of question scope.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to have the line width going from 5 to 0 to 5 and stop, this can be a solution. If the purpose is to manually stop animation, read Asperi's solution.

You can animate twice, first by changing the line width from 5 to 0 on the first half of the duration, then from 0 to 5 on the second half. You control this behaviour using two commands:

- on the `.animation()`, include a pre-defined `(duration:)`
- on change of the Boolean variable, change back from 0 to 5 using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter()`

Here's the sample code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var animate: Bool
    @State private var lineWidth = 5.0
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
        
            .stroke(Color.blue, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: lineWidth))
        
            // Instead of repeating, make it with a pre-defined duration.
            // The value here (0.25) is half of the total duration
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.25), value: lineWidth)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        
            // Change the line width when animate changes
            .onChange(of: animate) { _ in
                
                // Make it zero immediately
                lineWidth = 0
                
                // On the second half of the duration, make it 5 again
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
                    lineWidth = 5
                }
            }
    }
}

struct ContentViewPreviewer: View {
    @State var animate = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ContentView(animate: $animate)
            Button("Toggle") {
                animate.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```